# Emgu error when trying to copy VS2012 solution to another computer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, emgucv

I have a rather large VS2012 solution consisting of several projects which utilize the EMGU libraries.

The projects run successfully on one computer. However, when I try to copy the whole solution directory I come across an error: "The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception"

Any advice on how to correct this issue?